# Discoloration of cactus: Fungi or Mite?

Tags: cactus

I’ve been caring for this cactus for about 3 years now, and it seems happy based on the amount of growth.
Recently (about 2 months ago) I started to notice a discoloration/change to the outside of the cactus. I can’t tell if it’s from spider mites, or some kind of fungus. It’s in the same pot as another cactus that doesn’t have the same issues. Can someone help me identify what exactly is going on? Pictures attached...[image]

Comment: Distribution is wrong for sunburn ... has it been overwatered?

Comment: it almost looks bacterial from the "growth pattern" of the patches.

Comment: I don't think it has been overwatered but I could be wrong. It lives in a relatively small and shallow pot that gets quite a bit of sun. I'll take the advice and water it on a more strict routine, once a week, and see if that helps. The cactus has been growing nonstop for the last six months, so it's hard to know. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I'm also going to treat it with something for bacteria growth. Couldn't hurt.
I've read that Bordeaux mixture can be good for killing fungi and bacteria. Is there a recommended spray or brand? I treated my cactus with some Neem oil spray a couple weeks ago, simply because I had some on hand.